# Is there any spcecial meaning of "typedef" in C++?

Tags: c++, typedef

When I was reading stdc++ code, I felt confused about the below lines.
Here is a piece of code from stl_list.h.

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc>                                      
class _List_base                                                        
  : public _List_alloc_base<_Tp, _Alloc,                                
                            _Alloc_traits<_Tp, _Alloc>::_S_instanceless>
{                                                                       
public:                                                                 
  typedef _List_alloc_base<_Tp, _Alloc,                                 
                           _Alloc_traits<_Tp, _Alloc>::_S_instanceless> 
          _Base;  /* Is _Base a kind of type?*/                              
  typedef typename _Base::allocator_type allocator_type;                

  _List_base(const allocator_type& __a) : _Base(__a) {/* How can a type be initiated like this?*/                  
    _M_node = _M_get_node();                                            
    _M_node->_M_next = _M_node;                                         
    _M_node->_M_prev = _M_node;                                         
  }
}
```

What confused me is `_Base`. This name was defined by `typedef`. I think it is as kind of type. But `_Base` appears in initialization list.
How can I understand this usage? Or you please paste some useful links for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `typedef` declares an alias for a type - a shorthand, if you prefer.

Its syntax is exactly as if you were declaring a variable, but instead of a variable it creates an alias for the specified type:

```
int a;         // a is a variable of type int
typedef int B; // B is an alias for type int
```

(notice that often they say `typedef original-type alias`, but it's an incorrect rule - if fails for function pointers, for example - and it's one more rule to remember for no reason)

As for static members, the type alias is *scoped* - inside the class it's accessible without other qualifiers, from the outside it requires qualification (`_List_base::_Base`).

---

Coming to your specific case, it's just a shorthand to refer to the base class, which is `_List_alloc_base<_Tp, _Alloc, _Alloc_traits<_Tp, _Alloc>::_S_instanceless>` and would be definitely cumbersome to write fully every time.

It appears in the initialization list because the constructor is invoking the constructor of the base class - i.e. `_Base` - passing the parameter `__a`.

This could be easier to see if you could somehow "enlarge" the scope of the `typedef` and write:

```
template <class _Tp, class _Alloc>                                      
class _List_base                                                        
  : public _Base
{                                                                       
public:                                                                 
  typedef _List_alloc_base<_Tp, _Alloc,                                 
                           _Alloc_traits<_Tp, _Alloc>::_S_instanceless> 
          _Base;
  typedef typename _Base::allocator_type allocator_type;                

  _List_base(const allocator_type& __a) : _Base(__a) {
```

Answer (score 1):

It is used to define a custom type, based on a previously existing type. To provide an alias for a type you may say. `typedef` could be read as "define type" or "`type`-`def`inition".

You can have "chained" `typdef`s, i.e.:

```
typedef int Id;     // Define new type "Id"
typedef Id UserId;  // Define new type "UserId" based on a previously existing type
// This is possible since "Id" was already defined
```

And then just use it:

```
UserId uid = 0; //uid is a variable of type UserId, which is an alias for int
```

In the example you provided every time you use `_Base` you are using `_List_alloc_base<_Tp, _Alloc, _Alloc_traits<_Tp, _Alloc>::_S_instanceless>` under the hood, but in a shorter manner. Using that alias results in a cleaner and more compact block of code.

You may notice that the example also uses `typedef typename` in the following line:

```
typedef typename _Base::allocator_type allocator_type;
```

Note that `_Base` can be used in that line because it was already defined in the previous line. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18385418/5583153) for clarification on the combined use of `typedef` and `typename`, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/5583153) too.

---

From [this link](http://www.functionx.com/cpp/keywords/typedef.htm):

> The formula to follow is:
>
> `typedef [attributes] DataType AliasName;`
>
> The `typedef` keyword is required. The *attribute* is not.
>   The `typedef` keyword can be followed by any C++ built-in data type, including `int`, `short`, `signed`, `unsigned`, `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `double`, `long`, or `long double`. The data type can also be an existing class that either is provided by one of the libraries that ship with the C++ compiler. For example, it can be the string class. The data type can also be a pointer to a known type.

Even though this is a definition you will encounter many times for this keyword, it might be easier to think of it as `typedef declaration;` as pointed out by *Matteo Italia* in the comments below.

Comment: The `typedef [attributes] DataType AliasName;` is moot, and confused me to no end when I initially learned C and C++, because (for example) `typedef`s that involved function pointers made no sense at all under those fake premises. The right way to look at a `typedef` is: `typedef declaration;`, where declaration is exactly as you would declare a variable, only instead of a *variable* it declares an *alias* for its type.